# Использование итератора в С++

Tags: c++

Реализовать класс "Итератор", который имеет следующие функции: установка на начало списка, проверка конца списка, доступ к текущему элементу списка, переход к следующему элементу, переход к предыдущему элементу списка.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class list 
{
    struct node
    {
        T data;             //Значение
        node *next;         //Указатель на следующий элемент
    };
    node *head;             //Указатель на фиктивный элемент
    node *tile;             //Указатель на конечный элемент
    int size;                   //Размер вектора
    int sum_oper;               //Число операций
public:
    list();                 //Конструктор
    list(list<T> &a);               //Конструктор копирования
    ~list();                    //Деструктор
    void Add(T &new_data);          //Добавление элемента
    void Print();               //Вывод
    void RandList(int, int);            //Заполнить случайно
    bool Insert(T &ins_data, int num);      //Вставка
    bool Delete(int num);               //Удаление
    bool DelVal(T &val);            //Удаление по значению
    T&   Get(int);          //Чтение элемента по индексу
    bool Change(T &ch_data, int num);       //Запись элемента по индексу
    void Clear();               //Очистка списка
    int  Search(T &val);            //Поиск элемента по значению
    int  SumCount()     //Опрос количества операций
    {
        return sum_oper;
    };
    int  Size()       //Опрос размера списка
    {
        return size;
    };
    class Iterator
    {
        /*
        конструкторы
        методы (установка на начало, конец, к текущему, предыдущему, следущему)
        и т.д.
        понятия не имею как реализовать...
       */
    };
};
list<int> l;
int data;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------
//Конструктор
template<class T>
list<T>::list()
{
     head = new node;
     head->next = head;
     tile = NULL;
     it.Iter(head);
     size = 0;
     sum_oper = 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Конструктора копирования
template<class T>
list<T>::list(list<T> &a) 
{
    node *pcur, *new_node;
    head = new node;
    pcur = head;
    for(node *cur=a->head->next; cur!=a->head; cur=cur->next)
    {
         new_node = new node;
         new_node->data = cur->data;
         pcur->next = new_node;
         pcur = new_node;
    }
    pcur->next = head;
    tile = pcur;
    if(tile == head) tile = NULL;
    it.Iter(head);
    size = 0;
    sum_oper = 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Деструктор
template<class T>
list<T>::~list()
{
    Clear();
    delete head;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Добавление элемента в список
template<class T>
void list<T>::Add(T &new_data)
{
    node *cur = tile; 
    if(cur == NULL) cur = head; //добавление текущего элемента в голову списка 
    node *new_node = new node; //выделение памяти узла
    new_node->data = new_data; 
    cur->next = new_node;
    new_node->next = head;
    tile = new_node;
    size++;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Вывод списка на экран
template<class T>
void list<T>::Print()
{
    for(node *cur=head->next; cur!=head; cur=cur->next)
    {
         cout << setw(5) << cur->data;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Случайные значения
template<class T>
void list<T>::RandList(int rand_list_size, int rand_list_interval)
{
    Clear();
    srand((unsigned)time( NULL ));
    for(int i=0; i<rand_list_size; i++)
    {
        int r = rand()*rand()%rand_list_interval;
        Add(r);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Вставка нового элемента в позицию
template<class T>
bool list<T>::Insert(T &ins_data,int num)
{
    sum_oper = 0;
    int i = 0;
    node *new_node = new node;
    if(num > size+1 || num <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    node *cur = head;
    for(; i!=num-1; cur=cur->next)
    {
        i++;
        sum_oper++;
    }
    new_node->data = ins_data;
    new_node->next = cur->next;
    cur->next = new_node;
    size++;
    if(num == size) tile = new_node;
    return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Удаление элемента из позиции
template<class T>
bool list<T>::Delete(int num)
{   
    sum_oper = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if(num > size || num<=0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    node *cur = head;
    for(; i!=num-1; cur=cur->next)
    {
        i++;
        sum_oper++;
    }
    node *dcur = cur->next;
    cur->next = dcur->next;
    delete dcur;
    size--;
    return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Удаление по значению
template<class T>
bool list<T>::DelVal(T &val)
{   
    node *cur;
    int i = 1;
    if(val < 0 || head->next == head)
    {
        return false;
    }
    cur = head->next;

    node *pcur = head;
    for(; ((cur->data!=val)&&(cur!=head)); pcur=pcur->next)
    {
        i++;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    if (cur == head)
    {
        return false;
    }
    pcur->next = cur->next;
    delete cur;
    size--;
    return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Очистить список
template<class T>
void list<T>::Clear()
{
    node *cur = head->next;
    node *temp;
    while(cur != head)
    {
        temp = cur->next;
        delete cur;
        cur = temp;
    }
    head->next = head;
    tile = NULL;
    sum_oper = 0;
    size = 0;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Поиск элемента по индексу
template<class T>
T& list<T>::Get(int num)
{
    int i = 0;
    if((num > 0) && (num <= size))
    {
        if(num == size) return tile->data;
        node *cur = head;
        for(; i!=num; cur=cur->next)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return cur->data;
    }
    else throw -1;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Поиск элемента по значению
template<class T>
int list<T>::Search(T &val)
{   
    node *cur = head->next;
    sum_oper = 0;
    int i = 1;
    if(val < 0 || head->next==head)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for(; ((cur->data!=val)&&(cur!=head)); cur=cur->next)
    {
        i++;
        sum_oper++;
    }
    if (cur == head)
    {
        i=0;
    }
    return i;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Изменение элемента с заданным значением
template<class T>
bool list<T>::Change(T &ch_data, int num)
{
    int i=0;
    if(num > size || num <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    node *cur = head;
    for(; i!=num; cur=cur->next)
    {
        i++;
    }
    cur->data = ch_data;
    return true;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int Menu()
{
    system("cls");
    int i; //кнопка выбора
    cout << endl << "------       Меню:    ------" << endl
    << "1. Добавить элемент в список." << endl
    << "2. Заполнить список случайно. " << endl
    << "3. Показать список." << endl
    << "4. Вывести размер списка." << endl
    << "5. Вставка элемента." << endl
    << "6. Удаление элемента." << endl
    << "7. Поиск элемента по индексу." << endl
    << "8. Поиск элемента по значению." << endl
    << "9. Очистить список." << endl
    << "10. Изменить значение элемента." << endl
    << "11. Тест." << endl
    << "12. Итератор" << endl
    << "0. Выход." << endl;
    cout << "Выберите нужное действие: ";
    cin >> i;
    return i;
}
void selMenu()
{
    do
    {
        switch(Menu())
        {
        case 1:            //Добавить элемент
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Введите значение: ";
            cin >> data;
            l.Add(data);
            cout << "Значение добавлено." << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2:            //Ввод размера списка
        {   
            int rand_list_size;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Введите размер списка: ";
            cin >> rand_list_size;
            system("cls");
            l.RandList(rand_list_size, 100);
            cout << "Список заполнен случайными числами!" << endl;
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {   // вывод списка
            system("cls");
            if(l.Size() == 0) cout << "Список пуст!";
            else
                l.Print();
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 4:         //вывод размера
        {
            system("cls");
            if(l.Size() == 0) cout << "Список пуст!";
            else
                cout << "Размер списка: " << l.Size();
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 5:       //Вставка нового элемента в список в заданную позицию
        {
            int num;    
            system("cls");
            cout << "Введите значение: ";
            cin >> data;
            cout << endl << "Введите индекс: ";
            cin >> num;
            if(l.Insert(data, num)) cout << endl << "Новый элемент вставлен." << endl;

            else 
            {
                cout << "Элемент вставить не удалось!" << endl;
            }
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 6:        //Удаление элемента из списка из заданной позиции
        {
            system("cls");
            int num;
            cout << "Введите индекс удаляемого элемента ";
            cin >> num; //Задаем индекс удаляемого элемента
            //Если индекс введен правильно
            if(l.Delete(num)) cout << "Элемент " << num << " удален!" << endl; //то элемент с текущим индексов удаляется
            else //иначе выводим сообщение об ошибке
            {
                cout << "Ошибка! Неверный индекс." << endl;
            }
            getch();
            break;
        }
    case 7:      //Поиск элемента по заданному индексу
        {
            system("cls");
            int num;
            cout << "Введите индекс: ";
            cin >> num;
            try          //Если индекс задан неверно, (находится вне текущего размера)
            {
                cout << endl << endl << "Значение: " << l.Get(num) << endl;
            }
            catch(int) // то обрабатываем ошибку
            {
                cout << "Ошибка! Неверный индекс!" << endl;
            }
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 8: //Поиск элемента по заданному значению
        {
            system("cls");
            int val;
            cout << "Введите искомое значение: ";
            cin >> val;
            //Если такого значения в списке нет
            if(l.Search(val) == 0)  cout << "Не найдено!"; //то выводится вот это сообщение
            else cout << "Индекс искомого значения: " << l.Search(val); //иначе выводится результат
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 9: //Очистка списка
        {
            system("cls");
            l.Clear();
            cout << "Список очищен!" << endl;
            getch();
            break;
        }
        case 10:   //Изменение значения из списка с заданным индексом
        {
            int num = 0;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Введите индекс: ";
            cin >> num;
            cout << "Введите значение: ";
            cin >> data;
            //Если ввели значение и индекс вверно
            if(l.Change(data, num)) cout << "Значение изменено." << endl; // то выводится вот это сообщение
            else //Если индекс находится вне текущего рзмера 
            {
                cout << "Значение изменить не удалось!" << endl; // то выводится вот это сообщение
            }
            getch();
            break;
        }
        //тестирования трудоёмкости операций поиска, вставки и удаления.
        //Размер списка от 10 до 100000
        case 11:
        {
            l.Clear(); //Очистка списка
            int sum_search=0, sum_del=0, sum_ins=0;
            int test_size=0, rnd=0, oper=0, rnd_s=0, rnd_e;
            system("cls");
            cout << "Введите размер списка: ";
            cin >> test_size; //Задаем размер списка
            system("cls");
            oper = test_size / 10;
            if (oper > 1000) oper = 100;
            if (oper > 10000) oper = 10;
            srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
            l.RandList(test_size, 2*test_size);
            for(int i=0; i<oper; i++)
            {
                rnd = rand()*rand()%100;
                rnd_e = rand()*rand()%test_size;
                l.Delete(rnd_e);
                sum_del += l.SumCount();
                 rnd_e = rand()*rand()%test_size;
                l.Insert(rnd, rnd_e);
                sum_ins += l.SumCount();
                rnd_s = rand()*rand()%(2*test_size);
                l.Search(rnd_s);
                sum_search += l.SumCount();
            }
            cout << "Размер списка: " << test_size << endl << endl;
            cout << "Cредняя трудоёмкость операций: " << endl; 
            //среднее число просмотренных элементов списка
            cout << endl << "Поиск: " << (double)sum_search / oper << endl;
            cout << "Удаление: " << (double)sum_del / oper << endl;
            cout << "Вставка: " << (double)sum_ins / oper << endl;
            getch();
            break;
        }
        default: return;
        }
    }
    while (1);
}
void main()
{  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    system("cls");
    selMenu();
}
```

Comment: Слишком много кода. Вряд ли, для понимания проблемы, он нужен весь.

Да и собственно вопрос как-то затерялся в коде.

Comment: @lev_, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Как много методов ...

А судя по 

    struct node
    {
        T data;             //Значение
        node *next;         //Указатель на следующий элемент
    };

у Вас односвязный список. 

Советую сразу переделать на двусвязный:

    struct node
    {
        T data;             //Значение
        node *next, *prev;
    };

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Node, typename T>
class slist_iterator {
private:
    Node* ptr;
public:
    slist_iterator(void):ptr(NULL){}
    slist_iterator(Node* _ptr):ptr(_ptr){}
public:

    slist_iterator& operator ++ (void) {
        if(ptr != NULL)
            ptr = ptr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    slist_iterator operator ++ (int) {
        slsit_iterator it(*this);
        ++*this;
        return it;
    }

    T& operator*(void) {
        return ptr->val;
    }

    bool operator == (const Node* _ptr) const {
        return (ptr == _ptr);
    }

    bool operator != (const Node* _ptr) const {
        return (ptr != _ptr);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class slist {

    struct node {
        T val;
        node* next;
    };

private:
    node*  head;
    node*  tail;
    size_t cnt;
public:
    typedef slist_iterator<node, T> iterator;
    typedef slist_iterator<const node, const T> const_iterator;

    slist(void):head(NULL), tail(NULL), cnt(0){}
    ~slist(){
        this->clear();
    }

public:

    void add(const T& val){
        node* ptr = new node();
        if(ptr == NULL)
            return;
        ptr->val  = val;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        if(head == NULL)
            head = tail = ptr;
        else {
            tail->next = ptr;
            tail = ptr;
        }
        ++cnt;
    }

    //...

    node* begin(void) { return head; }
    node* begin(void) const { return head; }
    node* end(void)   { return NULL; }
    node* end(void) const { return NULL; }

    bool empty(void) const {
        return (head == NULL);
    }

    size_t size(void) const {
        return cnt;
    }

    void  clear(void){
        node* tmp;
        while(head != NULL){
            tmp  = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
        tail = NULL;
        cnt  = 0;
    }
};

int main(void){
    slist<int> ls;
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        ls.add(j+1);

    for(slist<int>::iterator it = ls.begin(); it != ls.end(); ++it)
        *it *= 10;

    slist<int>::const_iterator io = ls.begin();
    while(io != ls.end()){
        std::cout << *io << ' ';
        ++io;
    }
    return 0;
}
```